# Where/ where ...in/ where ... to

Tags: prepositions

A man is in the post office. He is sending a package to London.

> - Where is he sending the package?
>      - He's sending it ***to London***.

What if you ask about the place where the man is sending the package?

> - Where is he sending the package?
>      - He's sending it ***in the post office.***

Is it the correct way of asking that question?

Comment: The first is correct and has an implied **to**. The second question might be better asked: Where is he sending the package **from**? He's sending it **from** the post office.  The implied **to** is more usual than an implied **from**.

Answer (score 2):

When you use where, it has implied prepositions to, at, in. So the first question "Where is he sending the package?" is correct grammatically.

However, the second question isn't correct as the where doesn't have implied preposition from. So The correct question and answer are as follows:

Question: Where is he sending the package from?

Answer:   He is sending it from the post office.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the second sentence **incorrect** as you said, it's grammatically correct, it's just ambiguous. The preposition "from" goes well, but I think we can add the preposition "to" to the first sentence as well, eliminating the ambiguity. Am I wrong?